# How to use ansible with elasticsearch nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible

I am using ansible to search the cpu usage of elasticsearch nodes.

```
- name: Health check
      uri:

        url: http://{{ inventory_hostname }}:9200/_cat/nodes?v
        method: GET
        return_content: yes
        body_format: json
      register: health
    - uri:

        url: http://{{ inventory_hostname }}:9200/_cat/nodes?h=ram.percent
        method: GET
        return_content: yes
        body_format: json
      register: ram
```

I have to send an alert if the ram percentage is greater than a particular threshold with the corresponding node details.

How can this be done using ansible.

Here ram.content is like this:

```
"ram.content": "87\n82\n94\n94\n87\n"
```

How to get the corresponding nodes for each ram value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Python's split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on your string:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ ram.content.split('\n') }}"
```

Comment: how can i store it to a list?

Comment: What do you mean? It is a list.

Comment: i have to store it somewhere so that i can take the corresponding node. basically if the ram percent is higher for second node i need to send the details of that particular node